# Rails: Rendering a js.erb through an AJAX call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

From JavaScript, I'm calling a controller via AJAX like so:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/books'
}
```

In my controller I have:

```
def index
  render 'lightbox.js.erb'
end
```

In my routes I have:

```
resources :books do
  member do
    get :lightbox
  end
end
```

In lighbox.js.erb I have:

```
alert("Hello world!");
```

For some reason, the alert is never getting called. I don't get any error messages, either through the server or through Firebug. I'm at a loss for what could be going wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It turns out that on the client-side, my JavaScript was being rendered as text. I confirmed this by looking at the console feed. It said:

```
Started GET "/books/lightbox?book=4&username=tbaron&_=1344009191129" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-03 10:53:11 -0500
Processing by BooksController#lightbox as text
```

Those last two words should have read "as JS." After rooting around, I found this [blog post](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms-data-type-with-jquery/) which led to a surprisingly simple solution. Add "dataType: script" to the AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/books'
  dataType : 'script'
}
```

Thanks for your help, everyone!

Answer (score 7):

I think that's because you need to call `books.js` :

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/books.js',
  success: function(data) {
    eval(data);
  }
}
```

In index action :

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render 'lightbox'}
  end
end
```

And `lightbox.js.erb` should be in app/views/books

If it still doesn't work, try calling `books/index.js`
You can also use firebug/chrome to check what the server is responding to your ajax call

Comment: Still no luck. Also, Firebug does show that the server is responding. I even put a success callback in the AJAX, and it's triggering.

Comment: What is the response you are getting?

Comment: I'm getting my code as a response. I wonder why it's not triggering?

Comment: I typed pure nonsense into the js.erb, which would typically cause Firebug to throw a syntax error if it were actually trying to process the code. My guess is that it's being read as text for some reason. I'll play around with this and hopefully figure something out.

Comment: Ok I just figured out that you actually need to execute the JS... the get request will just get the code ... and do nothing with it ... I'll edit my answer

Comment: Unfortunately, my actual code (as opposed to "hello world" code) can't render in the success callback, so I've got to handle it in the js.erb. I wonder if there's some way to force execution inside the js.erb file? It's also worth noting that I've rendered other js.erb files using this method, the main difference being that I called those files from the server, as opposed to calling them through AJAX. I didn't have do anything special to get those ones to execute.

Comment: Yes, just eval response from server :>

Answer (score 1):

You can try this script for call your action in java script

```
var post_params = {};
var action = '/books/script_action';

$.post(action, post_params).success(function (data) {

     eval(data);

}).error(function (data) {

    alert("Erro to call a action controller");

});
```

And in your controller try this. I suggest creating a new action

```
def script_action
  render 'lightbox.js'
end
```

In routes file:

```
match "books/script_action/" => "books#script_action"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the controller:

```
respond_to :js
```

Answer (score 0):

In your index action, render without layout：

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render 'lightbox', layout: false}
end
```

this is work for me.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles upon this and simply wants to call a controller action that responds with a `js.erb` file, I've achieved it this way (with the help of [Anthony Alberto's Awesome Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11787335/7286108)).

**Controller Action**

```
def some_action
  ..
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render 'some_action' }
  end
end
```

**some_action.js.erb**

```
...
$('#someActionWrap').html('<%= j render "some/displaypartials/action_partial" %>')
...
```

**Ajax call**

```
var id = '<%= @someresource.id %>';
$.get('/someresource/' + id + '/action/', null, function(data){
    eval(data)
}, 'script');
```

Answer (score 0):

i have a similar problem on link_to helper but this were corrected using `remote:true`